# Unable to run mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>proman</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>


  <groupId>apps.proman</groupId>
  <artifactId>proman-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Project Management Application - RESTful API</name>
  <description>Project Management Application - RESTful API Implementation</description>

  <properties>
    <swagger.codegen.version>2.3.1</swagger.codegen.version>
    <swagger.codegen.generators.version>1.0.0-rc0</swagger.codegen.generators.version>
    <application.package>apps.proman.api</application.package>
    <endpoints.dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints</endpoints.dir>
    <supported.language>spring</supported.language>
    <supported.library>spring-boot</supported.library>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>apps.proman</groupId>
      <artifactId>proman-service</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <!-- Generate request/response models -->
    <profile>
      <id>generate-model</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
              <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                <language>${supported.language}</language>
                <library>${supported.library}</library>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                <modelPackage>${application.package}.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>${application.package}.rest</apiPackage>
                <configOptions>
                  <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                  <java8>true</java8>
                  <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                  <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                </configOptions>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-generators</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-rc0</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>authentication</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <inputSpec>${endpoints.dir}/authentication.json</inputSpec>
                  <language>${supported.language}</language>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>signup</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <inputSpec>${endpoints.dir}/signup.json</inputSpec>
                  <language>${supported.language}</language>
                </configuration>
              </execution>

              <execution>
                <id>usermanagement</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <inputSpec>${endpoints.dir}/usermanagement.json</inputSpec>
                  <language>${supported.language}</language>
                </configuration>
              </execution>

              <execution>
                <id>boardmanagement-v1</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <inputSpec>${endpoints.dir}/boardmanagement.json</inputSpec>
                  <language>${supported.language}</language>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>

          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

I am new here and this would be my first question, hope to get some inputs from my seniors here:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project proman-api: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Cannot load configuration class: apps.proman.api.PromanRestApplication: ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError
```

This is a huge roadblock as I am unable to open swagger.

Also a little gist: I am learning FSD from upgrad and I have an existing POM file (which we are advised not to edit).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Raksha Nair

Comment: Add more details..the single line does not help...there are a lot line before which give more details.. Recommendation: Upgrade the spring boot version (2.0.1.RELEASE) is bit old...

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project proman-api: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Cannot load configuration class: apps.proman.api.PromanRestApplication: ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).